# Django: division output from two sums

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

This is my current code:

```
data = data.values('number_of_houses',
                   'total',
                   'old_price',
                   )

return data.aggregate(number_of_houses_new=Sum('number_of_houses'),
                      total_new=Sum('total'),
                      house_percentage_new=Sum('number_of_houses') / Sum('total'),
                      old_price_new=Avg('old_price', output_field=IntegerField())
                      )
```

My problem is with `house_percentage_new`. The value is consistently 0. How do I go about dividing two Sums?

I'm using Django 1.11 and Python 3.6

Comment: The issue might be that you're dividing two integers which results in an integer. I.e. `1 / 2 = 0` because 0.5 is rounded down to 0. Adding ExpressionWrapper and a specific field type might help. Try this: `house_percentage_new=ExpressionWrapper(Sum('number_of_houses'), output_field=models.FloatField()) / ExpressionWrapper(Sum('total'), output_field=models.FloatField())`.

Comment: It works. Thanks. Do you want to add it as a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dividing integers always rounds numbers down (floors), so if the division result is between 0 and 1, it will always be 0. A workaround in Django ORM would be to add `ExpressionWrapper` and specify a `FloatField` as the output field like this:

```
house_percentage_new=ExpressionWrapper(Sum('number_of_houses‌​'), output_field=models.FloatField()) / ExpressionWrapper(Sum('total'), output_field=models.FloatField())
```

PS. You might get away with just one of the operands being float, but since I can't test it at the moment, it's up to you. And also this might work - and might not work as well:

```
house_percentage_new=ExpressionWrapper(Sum('number_of_houses‌​') / Sum('total'), output_field=models.FloatField())
```